# Trying to inflate a custom layout but not being able to

Tags: android

So I am trying to use a custom layout for my notepad part of my app, but I just can't seem to be able to make it appear, below I'll display the notepad activity itself, the layout file and the adapter class that I made to inflate it in the hopes that I can get help to solve it.

The Notepad Activity:

```
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;
import androidx.appcompat.widget.Toolbar;
import androidx.recyclerview.widget.LinearLayoutManager;
import androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView;
import java.util.List;

public class Notepad extends AppCompatActivity {

    Adapter adapter;
    List<Note> notes;
    RecyclerView recyclerView;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_notepad);

        Toolbar toolbar2 = findViewById(R.id.toolbar2);
        setSupportActionBar(toolbar2);
        DataBaseHelper db = new DataBaseHelper(this);
        notes = db.getNotes();
        recyclerView = findViewById(R.id.listOfnotes);
        recyclerView.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(this));
        adapter = new Adapter(this, notes);
        recyclerView.setAdapter(adapter);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.add_menu, menu);
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item){
        if(item.getItemId() == R.id.add){
                startActivity(new Intent(this, AddNote.class));
        }
        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }
}
```

The layout file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="#FAFAFA"
    android:padding="5dp">

    <androidx.cardview.widget.CardView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        app:cardCornerRadius="0dp"
        app:cardElevation="0dp"
        app:contentPadding="5dp"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        android:layout_marginBottom="5dp">

        <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content">


            <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
                android:id="@+id/constraintLayout"
                android:layout_width="83dp"
                android:layout_height="61dp"
                app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent">

                <ImageView
                    android:id="@+id/imageView"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    app:srcCompat="@drawable/ic_launcher_background"
                    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
                    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
                    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
                    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />
            </androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>

            <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/constraintLayout"
                app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent">

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/nTitle"
                    android:layout_width="0dp"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_marginStart="16dp"
                    android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
                    android:layout_marginEnd="16dp"
                    android:text="Sample Note Title"
                    android:textAlignment="viewStart"
                    android:textAllCaps="false"
                    android:textColor="@android:color/background_dark"
                    android:textSize="18sp"
                    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
                    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
                    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/nDate"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_marginStart="16dp"
                    android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
                    android:text="created : 7/31/2019"
                    android:textStyle="italic"
                    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
                    app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/nTitle" />

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/nTime"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_marginStart="16dp"
                    android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
                    android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
                    android:text="08:02"
                    android:textStyle="italic"
                    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
                    app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.0"
                    app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/nDate"
                    app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/nTitle" />

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/listId"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_marginStart="7dp"
                    android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
                    android:layout_marginBottom="20dp"
                    android:text="TextView"
                    android:visibility="gone"
                    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
                    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
                    app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/nTitle"
                    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />
            </androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>

        </androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>

    </androidx.cardview.widget.CardView>


</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

The adapter class:

```
import android.content.Context;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.TextView;

import androidx.annotation.NonNull;
import androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView;

import java.util.List;

public class Adapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<Adapter.ViewHolder> {

    LayoutInflater inflater;
    List<Note> notes;

    Adapter(Context context, List<Note> notes){
        this.inflater = LayoutInflater.from(context);
        this.notes = notes;
    }

    @NonNull
    @Override
    public Adapter.ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(@NonNull ViewGroup viewGroup, int viewType) {
        View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.custom_list_view, viewGroup, false);
        return new ViewHolder(view);
    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull Adapter.ViewHolder viewHolder, int i) {
        String title = notes.get(i).getTitle();
        String date = notes.get(i).getDate();
        String time = notes.get(i).getTime();
        Log.d("Title", "onBindViewHolder: Title -> " + title);
        viewHolder.nTitle.setText(title);
        viewHolder.nDate.setText(date);
        viewHolder.nTime.setText(time);
    }

    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return notes.size();
    }

    public static class ViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder{
        TextView nTitle, nDate, nTime;

        public ViewHolder(@NonNull View itemView) {
            super(itemView);
            nTitle = itemView.findViewById(R.id.nTitle);
            nDate = itemView.findViewById(R.id.nDate);
            nTime = itemView.findViewById(R.id.nTime);
        }
    }
}
```

Notepad Activity layout file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.appcompat.widget.LinearLayoutCompat
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="#ffffff"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    tools:context=".Notepad">

    <androidx.appcompat.widget.Toolbar
        android:id="@+id/toolbar2"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        android:background="@color/colorPrimary" />

    <androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView
        android:id="@+id/listOfnotes"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:background="#cd0190"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="1.0"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/toolbar2"
        app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.0" />
</androidx.appcompat.widget.LinearLayoutCompat>
```

[image]

Comment: No crashes, nor errors in the logcat that reference this. I am not getting anything displayed at all. Although I checked the database and it is storing the data.

Comment: My adapter is being used apparently. To give you a better view of my app, I have the notepad activity that should display the notes, an add button that takes to a separate activity that lets you enter the title and content, when I hit save it stores that data and I should be able to see it in the other activity, as for checking the rest, could you tell me how to check that?

Comment: Well, you could use the debugger, and set some breakpoints in the `Adapter` methods to make sure that they're being called, and returning the right things. Alternatively, you could add some log prints in those methods, and check for those in your logcat. [This developer page](https://developer.android.com/studio/debug) should be of some help for those options. As for determining whether the `RecyclerView` is actually visible, the simplest thing to do is probably to set some constrasting `android:background` color on it.

Comment: Ok, so I changed the background color of the recycler view and the change isn't visible, what can I do to make the ```recyclerView``` visible?

Comment: Well, that could be an issue with the `Activity` layout, though it might not be an issue at all; e.g., if it's got `wrap_content` dimensions, and an empty list. If you'd like to post `activity_notepad`, we can take a look at that, but you might still need to do the debugging stuff.

Comment: Edited with ```activity_notepad``` layout file.

Comment: You need to add an `android:orientation="vertical"` to the `<LinearLayoutCompat>`. Also, is there a particular reason you're using that, instead of a plain `<LinearLayout>`? Not that it's a big deal. Just curious.

Comment: No, no particular reason, should I change to the regular ```<LinearLayout>```?
And, by the way, no visible change.

Comment: Not necessarily, but unless you're supporting versions < API level 17, I think it is, there's really no reason to not use the regular `LinearLayout`. It's not a major issue; I was just curious...

Comment: Oh, yeah, you also need to change the `<RecyclerView>`'s `layout_width` and `layout_height` to `match_parent`. It looks like you moved it from a `<ConstraintLayout>`, but all of those `layout_constraint*` attributes won't work inside a `LinearLayout[Compat]`.

Comment: Nice it is showing the layout now, only problem is that the title is kind of weird, I'll edit the post with a picture.

Comment: You're apparently calling `toString()` directly on an `[AppCompat]EditText` when saving your notes, either explicitly or implicitly. You need to call `getText()` first; e.g., `noteTitle.getText().toString()`.

Comment: Thank you, it is working now. I can see the title just fine, and it is showing all of the notes made previously.